# cpp: How to find symbols removed in function level linking

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, aix, nm

I have a very huge executable built on IBM AIX. When I enable function level linking, the size of the task is 2.8GB, whereas when I disable function level linking task size goes up to 3.50GB.

This would most likely mean that there's additional object files that are pulled in which my application doesnt need, right? If so, how can I find the symbols that are removed with function level linking.

I tried to look at `nm` output on both tasks, but was clueless on what to look for, and what to diff

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `-Wl,--print-gc-sections` to `LDFLAGS`.